# cannot install phytools in ubuntu 18.04 with R 3.6

Tags: r, installation, dependencies

cannot install phytools

tried with devtools

```
library(devtools)
install_github("liamrevell/phytools")
```

and

```
install.packages("phytools")
```

I keep getting the same error

```
ERROR: dependency ‘mnormt’ is not available for package ‘phytools’
```

and I cannot install mnormt because

```
package ‘mnormt’ is not available (for R version 3.6.3)
```

gfortran is already installed in my system

```
GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
```

any help is highly appreciated,
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add the tag version to install command, for example: devtools::install_github('cran/mnormt@R-3.0.3')

Check what version you need and replace the tag after the '@'.

Answer (score 2):

The *current* version of `mnormt` depends on a the *current* version of R; you chose to remain a version behind.

So just install the previous version of `mnormt`, for example via

```
cd /tmp
wget https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/mnormt/mnormt_1.5-7.tar.gz
R CMD INSTALL mnormt_1.5-7.tar.gz
```

Prefix that last `INSTALL` command with `sudo`, or change the permission/group membership of `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library`, if R tells you it cannot write there.

Once `mnormt` is installed, proceed with the installation of `phytools`.

Comment: this one worked for me, although trying to install MetaboanalystR. Thanks

Comment: Good to know, and glad the answer was of use to someone!

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu Linux I cannot get R to update to the latest version (>4.0 at the time of writing), so, like Dirk suggests I have to install an older version of the package, one compatible with the version of R I am running.

My R version is 3.6.3, released feb 2020

I go to the `mnormt` page and click on "old sources" https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/mnormt/

I see that version 1.5-6 is the most recent release which is prior to my version of R

Following these pages: "Installing older versions of packages" https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/219949047-Installing-older-versions-of-packages I copy the relevant url into this code and run it in R

```
packageurl <- "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/mnormt/mnormt_1.5-6.tar.gz"
install.packages(packageurl, repos=NULL, type="source")
```

Which fixes my problem installing `mnormt` and also allows packages which depend on it to be installed in the standard way (as far as I tested it)